# How to stop the fingers scrolling in pivot in winui3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

```
<Pivot
    x:Name="pivot"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    Background="{StaticResource Background}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexPivotItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged"
    TabNavigation="Once">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border
                Height="50"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="16"
                    Text="{Binding}"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    
    <PivotItem
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        Header="Processing"
        ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,12,0">
            <local:ProcessingTabPage />
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Background="{StaticResource PivotBackground}" Header="PMMS Processing">
        <Grid Margin="-12,0,0,0">
            <local:ImagineTabPage />
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
</pivot>
```

I don't need that behavior. How can I stop the fingers scrolling functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by "fingers scrolling"? Do you mean touch screen?

Comment: Moving the cursor swiping in the mouse pad

Comment: Still don't understand. You only have 2 `PivotItem`s (Processing and PMMS Processing) right? What scrolling are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @Siva A mouse pad is not a input device. Do you mean a touchpad of a laptop?

Comment: Here I have 2 pivot item. Currently first one is selected. then i had put my 2 finger in the mousepad and try to swipe from right to left. It navigates to the 2nd pivot item. that the thing i want tor restrict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable manipulation on the headers and each `PivotItem`s:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.PivotControl.Loaded += PivotControl_Loaded;
        this.PivotControl.PivotItemLoading += PivotControl_PivotItemLoading;
    }

    private void PivotControl_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PivotControl
            .FindDescendant<ContentControl>(x => x.Name is "HeaderClipper") is ContentControl headerClipper)
        {
            headerClipper.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.None;
        }
    }

    private void PivotControl_PivotItemLoading(Pivot sender, PivotItemEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Item.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.None;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

`FindDescendatnt` comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.dependencyobjectextensions.finddescendants?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) NuGet package, but of course you can use the `VisualTreeHelper` instead.